# Destructuring and passing in full object simultaenously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple React component:

```
const FullContainer = ({
  backgroundColor,
  children,
}) => (
  <Container
    backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
  >
    {children}
  </Container>
);
```

I'm currently destructing the only two properties I expect my component to use, but I'd also like to pass in props and spread it in as well:

```
const FullContainer = (props, {
  backgroundColor,
  children,
}) => (
  <Container
    backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
  </Container>
);
```

Oddly enough, this breaks my page with no errors. I must be doing something wrong. Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Your second function expects *two* parameters. How many arguments do you pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`rest spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)  that provides the remaining properties which aren't destructured as an array like

```
const FullContainer = ({
  backgroundColor,
  children,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Container
    backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
  </Container>
);
```