# Destructuring a spreaded javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code

```
const foo = {props: {a: 'b'}};

const bar = (props) => {console.log({new: 'object', props})}

bar(foo)
```

results in the same exact output if i change `(props) =>` to `({...props}) =>`

What exactly is happening here?

The reason i am asking is because i am doing something similar in React with a pure component.

```
 export default ({ ...props }) => (
  <BaseLayout {...props} theme={defaultTheme} />
);
```

If i remove the spread operator in the parameter the component no longer renders.

I would appreciate if someone could explain exactly what is going on in both examples and if there is any difference between the JSX code and regular javascript, thanks.

Comment: The difference is that the rest element creates a new object while the plain parameter doesn't.

Comment: `{...props}` is spreading and creating a new object.

Comment: probably this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916422/destructuring-and-passing-in-full-object-simultaenously/52916433#52916433 or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a **shallow clone** of an object like `Object.assign()` did but in a cleaner way.

You can look at many use cases here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/